# How to get random documents from Cloud Firestore in Dart (for Flutter)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Lets say I have the following documents inside a Firestore collection:
[image]

How can I randomly get one or more documents without having to download them all? 
By the way, I've already seen [Dan McGrath's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801925/10997917), but he didn't specifically explain how to generate the auto-id for Flutter, also, I would love to see a complete example in Dart since his explanation was very generic.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no autoId generator inside the firestore sdk that you can use. But you can see (and copy) the implementation here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/utils/push_id_generator.dart

Comment: Those look like Realtime Database push IDs, not Firestore auto IDs.  Which database are you using?

Comment: @ZeRj That answers part of the question, however how would the query code look like?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I've come across the same issue after reading Dan's answer.

Comment: @Bobthebuilder24 unfortunately I haven't found the solution for this problem...

Comment: @Bobthebuilder24 take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Dan's answer, here's my current implementation.

```
static const AUTO_ID_ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
static const AUTO_ID_LENGTH = 20;
  String _getAutoId() {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    final random = Random.secure();

    final maxRandom = AUTO_ID_ALPHABET.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < AUTO_ID_LENGTH; i++) {
      buffer.write(AUTO_ID_ALPHABET[random.nextInt(maxRandom)]);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
  }
```

Code to query:

```
final autoId = _getAutoId();

final query = ref
    .where("qId", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: autoId)
    .orderBy("qId")
    .limit(count);
QuerySnapshot response = await query.getDocuments();
if (response.documents == null || response.documents.length == 0) {
  final anotherQuery = ref
      .where('qId', isLessThan: autoId)
      .orderBy('qId')
      .limit(count);
  response = await anotherQuery.getDocuments();
}
```

Some explainations:

1. qId is a field of my document. It's same as the documentId.
2. This implementation is based on Bi-directional, according to Dan's
   answer. We still have unfairly result but I'm ok with that. If someone have better algorithm, please share.
3. _getAutoId() is re-written based on Java code of firebase library.

If you have any questions, please ask. I will try to help as much as I could.

Have a nice day!